# Exposé for ubuntu 19.10 like in macOS with center-mouse click?

Tags: mouse, 19.10

I'm a macOS user that is starting to use Ubuntu 19.10 in his work intensively.

I love how Exposé works on macOS and I can see that a similar feature when I click on the `super` button on the keyboard. However, I would love to have the same feature using the mouse. The mouse has a wheel and the wheel is a button.

How can I config that button to trigger the Exposé-like feature in Ubuntu 19.10?

I've been trying to use CompizConfig Settings Manager, but… it's not working with the mouse. It's asking for which button to use and I've tried to set several —there are like 20 buttons— and none of those worked